# perforce equivalent of svnversion

Tags: perforce

Is there something similar to svnversion command in perforce ?

The project I'm working on has a release shell script. It would be nice if that script could check that the local copy of the repo has no modifications and no mixed versions. It would also be nice if the last commit number could be stored in the script output too. I used to do this using svnversion but now I must use perforce.

I thought I was used to CLI and would have no problem looking for what I wanted with p4 help but instead I was made humble again. ;-)

Comment: What is a "mixed version"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood what you need, but can't you just use the latest changelist number? First sync your workspace, then to get the latest changelist number, see this answer: [Get the changelist number of current workspace directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744067/265249)

Comment: Thanks that's part of what I need.
Svnversion also tells you if you have modified files or files forced to an older version. (Example : "40:45M" means file versions in your directory start at 40 and end at 45. The M tells you that some changes have not been submited). With that kind of output it is easy for a release script to check if the release will be reproducible in the future. I'd like to do that with perforce, if possible.

Comment: Personally I don't see why you need the oldest changelist number in your project. Around here we've got some legacy libraries which are rarely modified and thus the lowest changelist number will always correspond to those. You're situation might of course be different. As for the "M" you could use p4 opened to see if any files are open for edit which means that there might be unsubmitted changes.

Comment: Thanks again, with p4 opened I'm almost there. I don't need the oldest changelist I just need to know if a file has been forced to some older revision (using "Get Revision" in p4v for example). I managed to do that using p4 fstat (checking have revision vs head revision) and a bit of scripting.