# Retrieving the current change list number of a Perforce Workspace including reverts

Tags: perforce

The command `p4 changes -m1 //path/to/your/project/...#have` to get the current changelist, as shown by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9731415/368599), works great until we have a commit that reverts the commit immediately before it.

For example, if I have the following setup:

```
4 - CL#3 was reverted and submitted here
3 - Somebody submitted this CL
2 - <= Current workspace is here
1
0
```

- I run `p4 changes -m1 //path/to/your/project/...#have`, I get `2` as expected
- I then sync to `4` and run the command again, but I still get `2`. I assume this is because there is no new file locally and perforce still thinks I am on `2` when I should be on `4`.

This is an issue because it breaks some scripts that run on new CLs that are coming in. Is it possible to either ignore such CLs or adjust the command in some way to know that are on `4` even though there are no file changes (because `4` is a revert of `3`)?

Comment: nb “revert” means something different in Perforce — the situation you’re describing here is common to any changelist consisting solely of *deletes*.  The `p4 cstat` command might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Reproducing your setup by adding a file in change 3 and then deleting it in change 4, we can indeed see that `changes -m1 #have` returns change 2:

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 changes
Change 4 on 2023/01/26 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 'delete ola'
Change 3 on 2023/01/26 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 'add ola'
Change 2 on 2023/01/26 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 'add bar'
Change 1 on 2023/01/26 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 'add foo'
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 sync @4
@4 - file(s) up-to-date.
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 changes -m1 "#have"
Change 2 on 2023/01/26 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 'add bar'
```

This is because `changes -m1 #have` is just returning the maximum change among those returned by `p4 files #have`:

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 files "#have"
//stream/main/test/bar#1 - add change 2 (text)
//stream/main/test/foo#1 - add change 1 (text)
```

We do not have any file belonging to change 4, because change 4 consists solely of deleted revisions, which by definition are never synced to the workspace.

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 files @=4
//stream/main/test/ola#2 - delete change 4 (text)
```

When we sync to change 4, we don't get `ola#2`, we get `ola#none`, exactly as if we'd synced to change 2 (or any change where `ola` does not exist as a non-deleted file):

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 sync @4
@4 - file(s) up-to-date.
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 sync @2
@2 - file(s) up-to-date.
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 have ola
ola - file(s) not on client.
```

At this point it's actually equally correct to say that we're synced to either change 2 *or* change 4, since either will give us the same set of files.  In fact, if we diff the depot at those two changelists, we can see that those two points in time are effectively identical:

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 diff2 -q ...@2 ...@4
...@2 - no differing files.
```

If we want to divine change 4 from our current sync state rather than just the effectively identical change 2, the `p4 cstat` command is a useful tool -- this will iterate through all the changes for which our workspace contains all revisions up to that point:

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro:test samwise$ p4 cstat
... change 1
... status have

... change 2
... status have

... change 4
... status have
```

Since we `have` all changes up thru 4 according to `p4 cstat`, that is likely to be the best answer to the question "what change am I synced to?"

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer Samwise. I found that `cstat` will report that I have certain changes even if we manually sync to a previous CL such that no new files remain in our workspace e.g. I update to 4, but find that there's a bug and go back to 2 (by syncing up to that CL from the depot). However, `p4 cstat` still reports I am on 4 even though that's no longer true.

Comment: I tried to explain this in my answer -- if your setup matches the one in my example (which I think it does, based on your description) you are synced to 2 **and** 4 *at the same time* because **they correspond to identical sets of files**.  If you sync from 4 "back to 2" in this scenario you haven't changed your workspace contents at all, so it's still correct to report that you're synced to 4.  Or 2.  They're *the same thing*.  I demonstrated this in multiple different ways in my answer.  You can see that when I'm synced to @4 and I sync @2, I get the message "up to date".

Comment: sorry what I meant was: assuming I am on `CL 4` and then sync to `CL 0`, `cstat` would still say that I have `change 4` even though I am on `CL 0` now. I am not sure what the mechanism is by which `cstat` differs from `#have` but these are the results I am getting locally. Which in turn means `cstat` gives me the incorrect information about what I am currently synced to. It appears to 'remember' that I was synced to `4` and reports that as `status have` even though locally I have all the files from `CL 0` and nothing newer.

Comment: If you sync back to #none, `cstat` should now show you that you `need` changes 1 and 2.  It shows that you "have" change 4 because change 4 in itself consists solely of revisions that don't need to be synced, but you don't have the changes up thru 4, just 4 itself (so `@=4` as opposed to `@4`).